# Array class that will accept an braced-init-list and deduce length

Tags: c++, c++17, initializer-list, template-argument-deduction, c++20

This has been asked before, but I'm curious to see if anything has changed in newer C++ standards. Any current or future standard is acceptable.

**Q**: Is there anyway to create an Array class that can be initialized with a braced-init-list without having to manually specify the array length, with elements stored on the stack, and doesn't require a 'make_array' function.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
struct Array
{
    T items[N];
};

Array<int> foo = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Since `initializer_list` is not templated on the size, a constructor using it won't do the job. Deduction guides in C++17 *nearly* work, but you have to omit the type parameter and all items must have exactly the same type

```
Array foo = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Works
Array<int> foo = { 1, 2, 3 }; // Doesn't work
Array foo = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0f }; //Doesn't work
```

A constructor that takes a c-array doesn't appear to work because an `initializer_list` won't convert to a c-array.

Is the `braced-init-list` to `T[N]` that happens in `int foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` purely compiler magic that can't be replicated in code?

EDIT: The spirit of this question is about the *exact* syntax above. No make_array, no extra template argument, explicit item type, no double braces, no dynamic allocations. If a trivial Array requires a bunch of modern C++ tomfoolery and still can't manage to support standard syntax then it's just a bad engineering trade-off in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe you could create something much like `std::array`, but force the deduction guide by using some tag type as the first constructor argument. Would look something like `Array foo = {Tag<int>{}, {1, 2, 3}};`. (I haven't thought this all the way through yet...)

Comment: @BoBTFish - interesting idea: should permit to explicit the type, bypassing the problem that you can't explicit a template parameter using template guides; IMHO, you should elaborate it and propose it as an answer.

Comment: I don't know what 'making it a placeholder' means. I also don't know where type ambiguity makes it into the equation. It boils down to: it should be possible to write a constructor that takes a braced-init-list and has a compile-time known size. I'm not looking to change std::array.

Answer (score 14):

You can work around the need for all the types in the list to be the same by using an explicit deduction guide:

```
template <class... T>
Array(T&&... t) -> Array<std::common_type_t<T...>, sizeof...(T)>;

Array foo = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0f }; // Deduces Array<double,3u>
```

Comment: This is the closest I've seen to an answer, falling short only in that the array size is not part of the template.

Comment: @StevenW.Klassen It *is* a part of the template (a second template parameter). Template parameters of the deduction guide don't match template parameters of the class here.

Answer (score 5):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news, but I believe that at the current time (at least as of C++17) the answer to your question is "no" there is no way that would meet all of your given requirements. That said, there are solutions posted here that come close, but they all fall short in one or more of your requirements.

I also suspect that the answer will remain "no" in the near future. Not that I'm a prophet, but the direction of the last few C++ versions would seem to imply that a `make_array` solution is more likely to be what is added rather than more direct language support.

**Explanation**

Allow me to explain why in a little more detail.

*First* consider the C++17 deduction guides. I won't go into detail on them as they are discussed suitably by other answers on this question. They do come very close to what you are asking but do seem to fall short in one way or the other. (Although the answer by @max66 would seem to meet all your requirements except for the extra brackets. If his syntax in fact works you may want to consider that answer as "close enough".)

*Next* consider a variatic templates solution. In order to automatically determine N you would need a series of overloaded functions (basically one with a single argument and one that takes a single argument and the rest of the variatic templates). But that would essentially be equivalent to some form of `make_array` so it doesn't count either.

*Finally*, the only other option I could see would be based on an initializer_list. The question is how to determine N from that list. In C++11 this would be obviously impossible since the only access to the size of the list is `const` and not `constexpr`. However as of C++14 the `size()` method is in fact `constexpr` so you would think it is at least theoretically possible to get the compiler to deduce N based on that. Unfortunately to do this you would need to make N (a template parameter) default to a value of something in the class constructor (the initializer list). I have been unable to determine any means of doing this in the present form of the language.

**How I think a future version could support this**

*One way* to support this would be to follow the examples of other languages and add direct language support, bridging a syntax to certain classes. But this essentially makes some classes "special". Consider the following line in Swift:

```
let ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

In this example `ar` is an object of the type `Array<Int>`. But this is done by direct compiler support, i.e. "Array" is a special case. No matter what you do you could not write a MyArray class that would perform the same way (other than perhaps having MyArray accept an Array as a construction option). It is certainly possible for the C++ standard to be extended to do something similar, but C++ tends to try to avoid those "special" cases. Besides, an argument could be made that

```
auto ar = make_array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

is in fact a clearer representation of the intent than would be something like the following: (suggesting the character 'A' to distinguish this from an initializer list)

```
auto ar = A{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

*Another way*, more in line with current C++ syntax, to do this would be to add the N parameter to the initializer_list template class. After all since `size()` is now `constexpr` the size must be known at compile time, so why not make it available as a template parameter? It could suitably default so that it could rarely be needed, but it would allow classes (both standard ones like `std::array` and custom ones like you are proposing) the possibility of tying the N in the `Array` template to the `N` in the `initializer_list`. Then you should be able to write something along the following lines:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
struct Array 
{
    explicit Array(std::initializer_list<N> il);
}
```

Of course the trick would be to make this `initializer_list` change in a fashion that does not break a lot of existing code.

I suspect the standards committee will not follow either of these paths, but will more likely add the experimental `make_array` method. And I'm not convinced that is a bad idea. We are used to `make_...` in many other parts of the language, so why not here as well?

Comment: My answer isn’t make_array, my answer is no there isn’t at the current time. The experimental make_array may be an indication that something is perhaps being considered.

Comment: That said, there are some techniques being listed here that could yet prove me wrong. (Perhaps the answer is not ‘no’.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21359169)

Comment: The reviewers have a divided opinion of my post with half saying delete and half saying it is ok. Before going the delete route, I'm going to rephrase my answer and explain in more detail why I believe the correct answer is in fact (and unfortunately) "no".

Answer (score 1):

> Deduction guides in C++17 nearly work, but you have to omit the type parameter and all items must have exactly the same type

Not necessarily.

Yes, you can't explicit the type parameter, but you can decide it according the types of the items.

I imagine two reasonable strategies: (1) the type of the `Array` is the type of the first item, following the `std::array` way, so writing the following deduction guide

```
template <typename T, typename ... Us>
Array(T, Us...) -> Array<T, 1u + sizeof...(Us)>;
```

(but observe that a C++ program where a `Us` type is different from `T`, for a `std::array`, is ill formed) or (2) follows the metalfox's suggestion and select the item's common type

```
template <typename ... Ts>
Array(Ts...) -> Array<std::common_type_t<Ts...>, sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

> Is the braced-init-list to `T[N]` that happens in int `foo[] = { 1, 2, 3 };` purely compiler magic that can't be replicated in code?

Are you thinking in a deduction guide as follows ?

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
Array(T const (&)[N]) -> Array<T, N>;
```

Works but with a couple of drawbacks: (1) you have to add a couple of brackets using it

```
//    added ---V         V--- added
Array foo1 = { { 1, 2, 3 } }; // Works
```

and (2) remain the problem that all items must have the same type

```
Array foo2 = { {1.0, 2.0, 3.0f} }; //Doesn't work: incompatible types
```

or the compiler can't deduce the type `T`

P.s.: what's wrong with a `make_array()` function ?

P.s.2: I suggest to give a look at BoBTFish's answer to see a nice method to  bypass the impossibility to explicit a template argument using deduction guides.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that allows you to specify the type. We use an extra argument to specify the type, so that we can still use the deduction guide to pick up the size. I don't consider it pretty though:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Tag { };

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct Array {
    T data_[N];

    template <typename... U>
    Array(Tag<T>, U... u)
      : data_{static_cast<T>(u)...} // cast to shut up narrowing conversions - bad idea??
    {}
};

template <typename T, typename... U>
Array(Tag<T>, U...) -> Array<T, sizeof...(U)>;

int main()
{
    Array a{Tag<double>{}, 1, 2.0f, 3.0};
    for (auto d : a.data_) {
        std::cout << d << '\n';
    }
}
```

This is clearly not a full implementation of such a class, just to illustrate the technique.

Comment: Nice; I suggest to add, a SFINAE enable check in template signature (something as `template <typename ... U, typename = std::enable_if_t<N == sizeof...(U)>>` (or maybe is enough `sizeof...(U) <= N`) to avoid that someone can write something as `Array<int, 2>  a{Tag<int>{}, 1, 2, 3};`

Answer (score 0):

You had asked this:

> Q: Is there anyway to create an Array class that can be initialized with a braced-init-list without having to manually specify the array length, and without a 'make_array' function.

I have worked on an implementation of a class that behaves in the manner you are describing only it has a little bit more complexity to it but still fairly simple, readable, reusable, portable and generic.

I was not able to have a `T items[]` array as a direct member in the class. I had to use a `T* items` instead and create an overloaded `operator[]` in the derived class to mimic the behavior of an array. This doesn't mean that there isn't any work around to this as others have shown. I just find that this is one possible solution without having to specify the size of the array.

I use a base class to store the elements from the constructor either by means of an `std::initializer_list` or of a `variadic constructor`. The class templates themselves are not a variadic template only their constructor's are. The base class stores the values from the `initializer_list` or `parameter pack` into an `std::vector`. The inherited class stores the contents from the `vector` into `T*` by calling the `data()` function of the vector class.

```
template<typename T>
class ParamPack {
protected:
    std::vector<T> values_;
    size_t size_;
public:
    template<typename... U>
    ParamPack( U... u ) : 
      values_{ static_cast<T>(u)... }, 
      size_( sizeof...(U) ) {}

    template<typename ... U>
    ParamPack( std::initializer_list<std::is_same<T, U...>( U...)> il ) : 
      values_( il ), size_( il.size() ) {}

    std::vector<T>& operator()() { return values_; }

    size_t size() const { return size_; }
};    

template<typename T>
class Array : public ParamPack<T> {
private:
    T* items_;
public:
    template<typename... U>
    Array( U... u ) : ParamPack<T>::ParamPack( u... ) {
        items_ = this->values_.data();
    }

    template<typename... U>
    Array( std::initializer_list<U...> il ) : ParamPack<T>::ParamPack( il ) {
        items_ = this->values_.data();
    }

    T& operator[]( size_t idx ) {
        return items_[idx];
    }

    T operator[]( size_t idx ) const {
        return items_[idx];
    }

    T* data() const { return items_; }
};

int main() {
    try {
        // Parameter Pack Examples:
        // Variadic Constructor { ... }
        std::cout << "ParamPack<T> Examples:\n";
        std::cout << "Using ParamPack<T>'s Variadic Constructor\n";
        ParamPack<int> pp1( 1, 2, 3, 4  );
        std::cout << "Size: " << pp1.size() << " | Elements: ";
        for( auto& v : pp1() ) {
            std::cout << v << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';      

        std::cout << "Using ParamPack<T>'s Variadic Constructor with an Initializer List\n";
        ParamPack<int> pp2( { 5, 6, 7, 8 } );
        std::cout << "Size: " << pp2.size() << " | Elements: ";
        for( auto& v : pp2() ) {
            std::cout << v << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        std::cout << "Using ParamPack<T>'s initializer_list constructor\n";
        std::initializer_list<int> il{ 9,10,11,12 };
        ParamPack<int> pp3( il );       
        std::cout << "Size: " << pp3.size() << " | Elements: ";
        for( auto& v : pp3() ) {
            std::cout << v << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";    

        // Array Examples:
        std::cout << "Array<T> Examples:\n";
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s initializer_list Constructor\n";
        Array<int> arr( il );       
        for( size_t i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";

        // Using Variadic Constructor
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Variadic Constructor\n";
        Array<int> testA( 9, 8, 7, 6 );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < testA.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << testA[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        Array<std::string> testB( "Hello", " World" );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < testB.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << testB[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";

        // Using Constructor w/ Initializer List
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Variadic Constructor with Initializer List\n";
        Array<int> testC( { 105, 210, 420 } );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < testC.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << testC[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";

        // Using Initializer List with =
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Initializer List with =\n";
        Array<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        for( size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << a[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';                

        Array<char> b = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < b.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << b[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        Array<double> c = { 1.2, 3.4, 4.5, 6.7 };
        for( size_t i = 0; i < c.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << c[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n"; 

        // Using Initializer List directly
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Initalizer List directly\n";
        Array<uint32_t> a1{ 3, 6, 9, 12 };
        for( size_t i = 0; i < a1.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << a1[i] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";

        // Using user defined data type
        struct Point {
            int x_, y_;
            Point( int x, int y ) : x_( x ), y_( y ) {}
        };
        Point p1( 1, 2 ), p2( 3, 4 ), p3( 5, 6 );

        // Variadic Constructor
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Variadic Consturctor with user data type\n";
        Array<Point> d1( p1, p2, p3 );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < d1.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << "(" << d1[i].x_ << "," << d1[i].y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        // Initializer List Construtor (reversed order)
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Initializer List Constructor with user data type\n";
        Array<Point> d2( { p3, p2, p1 } );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < d2.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << "(" << d2[i].x_ << "," << d2[i].y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        // Initializer List Version = {...} p2 first
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s  = Initializer List with user data type\n";
        Array<Point> d3 = { p2, p1, p3 };
        for( size_t i = 0; i < d3.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << "(" << d3[i].x_ << "," << d3[i].y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        // Initializer List Directly p2 first p1 & p3 swapped
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s Initializer List directly with user data type\n";
        Array<Point> d4{ p2, p3, p1 };
        for( size_t i = 0; i < d4.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << "(" << d4[i].x_ << "," << d4[i].y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';  

        std::initializer_list<Point> ilPoints{ p1, p2, p3 };
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s initializer_list Constructor with user data type\n";
        Array<Point> d5( ilPoints );
        for( size_t i = 0; i < d5.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << "(" << d5[i].x_ << "," << d5[i].y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n\n";    

        // Need a local copy of the vector instead?
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s base class's operator()() to retrieve vector\n";
        std::vector<Point> points = d4(); // using operator()()
        for( auto& p : points ) {
            std::cout << "(" << p.x_ << "," << p.y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

        // Need a local copy of the pointer instead?
        std::cout << "Using Array<T>'s data() to get the contents of its internal pointer\n";
        Point* pPoint = nullptr;
        pPoint = d4.data();
        for( size_t i = 0; i < d4.size(); i++ ) {
            std::cout << "(" << pPoint[i].x_ << "," << pPoint[i].y_ << ") ";
        }
        std::cout << '\n';

    } catch( const std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

*-Output-*

```
ParamPack<T> Examples:
Using ParamPack<T>'s Variadic Constructor
Size: 4 | Elements: 1 2 3 4
Using ParamPack<T>'s Variadic Constructor with an Initializer List
Size: 4 | Elements: 5 6 7 8 
Using ParamPack<T>'s initializer_list Constructor
Size: 4 | Elements: 9 10 11 12

Array<T> Examples:
Using Array<T>'s initializer_list Constructor
9 10 12 12

Using Array<T>'s Variadic Constructor
9 8 7 6
Hello World

Using Array<T>'s Constructor with Initializer List
105 210 420

Using Array<T>'s Initializer List with =
1 2 3 4
a b c d
1.2 3.4 5.6 7.8

Using Array<T>'s Initializer List directly
3 6 9 12

Using Array<T>'s Variadic Constructor with user data type
(1,2) (3,4) (5,6)
Using Array<T>'s Variadic Constructor With Initializer List of user data type
(5,6) (3,4) (1,2)
Using Array<T>'s = Initializer List with user data type
(3,4) (1,2) (5,6)
Using Array<T>'s Initializer List directly with user data type
(3,4) (5,6) (1,2)
Using Array<T>'s initializer_list Constructor with user data type

Using Array<T>'s base class's operator()() to retrieve vector
(3,4) (5,6) (1,2)   
Using Array<T>'s data() to get the contents of its internal pointer
(3,4) (5,6) (1,2)
```

Now this is a little more robust as it has operators that are available from both the parent and child class, from the parent class you can get the stored `vector` directly from its `operator()()`. From the child class you can index into the child's stored pointer from `operator[]()` and there is a function to return it's size. The template itself does not contain a `size_t N` template argument since the size is stored internally in the base class and is determined by the size of its vector. With this I'm treating `T* p` as if it was `T p[size]`. This class is still not without some limitations.

*-Valid Construction-*

```
Array<int> a( 1, 2, 3, 4 ); // Variadic Constructor Okay
Array<int> a( {1,2,3,4} ); // Initializer List Constructor Okay
Array<int> a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // Initializer List Okay
Array<int> a{ 1,2,3,4 }; // Initializer List Okay
```

*-Limitations-*

However you have to `explicitly` instantiate the template as these will not work as they all generate a compiler error.

```
Array a( 1,2,3,4 );
Array a( {1,2,3,4} );
Array a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
Array a{ 1,2,3,4 };
```

*-Note-* There maybe more that can be done to make this more efficient, maybe even thread safe or exception safe, but this is just a generalization of the class design.

---

*Please let me know what you think about this:*

Comment: I appreciate your thoroughness. However, this answer boils down to 'allocate and copy elements into a vector' and it's needlessly complex even for that case. The defining features of an array are no dynamic allocation and a compile time known size.

Comment: @Adam I know, but the problem with trying to not specific the array's size by inferring it from the amount of the parameters passed into the initializer list's constructor will not work because the size of the array has to be known at compile time. Even though you are calling the constructor on the class, the compiler has to set aside memory for the class and all of its members before it can call its ctor and thus it can not create the array without knowing how many elements of type `T` to reserve for the class's construction.

Comment: @Adam also your question is a very good question. I posted this answer because I enjoyed the attempt at trying to mimic a C arrays behavior. There are no direct issues with the code above, maybe some room for efficiency, but in the output section I'm kind of wording some of it wrong. Non of the examples are using the 2nd constructor of the two classes. They are all using the 1st constructor which is the variadic version. I'm working on it now to update the main and it's output to make it more clear.